# debian wheezy to jessie apache start\cloudflare issue

Tags: apache, debian, cloudflare

I apt-get dist-upgraded from Debian Wheezy to Jessie and kept my config files for my LAMP stack and now I'm getting the following error when attempting to start Apache: (I'm totally stumped here. Why would apache\the cloudflare module not load?)

```
root@county:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
[....] Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
failed!
```

---

```
root@county:~# systemctl status apache2.service -l
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-07-16 20:58:34 EDT; 21s ago
Process: 2166 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 16 20:58:34 county systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jul 16 20:58:34 county apache2[2166]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
Jul 16 20:58:34 county apache2[2166]: The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Jul 16 20:58:34 county apache2[2166]: Output of config test was:
Jul 16 20:58:34 county apache2[2166]: apache2: Syntax error on line 244 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cloudflare.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cloudflare.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cloudflare.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror
Jul 16 20:58:34 county apache2[2166]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jul 16 20:58:34 county apache2[2166]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jul 16 20:58:34 county systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 16 20:58:34 county systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jul 16 20:58:34 county systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
```

---

```
root@county:~# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Thu 2015-07-16 20:51:26 EDT, end at Thu 2015-07-16 20:59:02 EDT. --
Jul 16 20:59:01 county CRON[2208]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:01 county CRON[2206]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:01 county CRON[2209]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:01 county CRON[2211]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:01 county CRON[2203]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:01 county CRON[2201]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:01 county CRON[2207]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:02 county CRON[2202]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:02 county CRON[2200]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 16 20:59:02 county CRON[2204]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Cloudflare.load contains the following:

```
LoadModule cloudflare_module  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cloudflare.so
```

mod_cloudflare.so is from     https://github.com/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare

Update: The issue is far more than Cloudflare.

```
 Jul 16 22:27:41 county apache2[1674]: apache2: Syntax error on line 265 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration...irectory
 Jul 16 22:27:41 county apache2[1674]: Action 'configtest' failed.

 Jul 16 22:27:41 county apache2[1674]: apache2: Syntax error on line 265 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf.d/: No such file or directory

 Jul 16 22:29:18 county apache2[1963]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 89 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
 Jul 16 22:29:18 county apache2[1963]: Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

My apache2.conf (I can't even get the version number [its the latest version] after upgrading from Wheezy to Jessie because I get an error message regarding this config):

http://paste.debian.net/283153/

Answer (score 0):

do you modify the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-main.list replacing the wheezy word with jessie?
If you do not change this file, you will have the package build for the old stable and not for the current stable debian version.
So, put jessie instead of wheezy on /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-main.list, run

```
apt-get update
```

and then

```
apt-get upgrade
```